# How do I get the amount of time something is occupied using only timestamps?

Tags: java

I have a bunch of timestamps that are stamped with the applicable operation(bending, laser, etc) I have the hours a day we are open (16 hours, or particular hours like 2:30AM - 11:00PM)

Based on a bunch of timestamps(with start and end times) with that operation and the user working it, how can I determine  of the 18 hours we are open, how many hours is that machine running for?

I submitted the sum of all of the differences in the times but apparently what is wanted is compare every timestamp and find the hours aren't occupied, eg if 2-10 is when we're open and there is one batch ran from 2-4 and another from 3-4 then we are unoccupied for 6 hours.

Is this possible, if so, how?

Comment: It would be good if you can post example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the end time and start times are paired.

At the simplest:

busy = sum of all (end time - start time) for each activity.

Take 2:

1. Create a class that represents a TimeSpan (has a start time and an end time).
2. Implement a comparator for the TimeSpan class that sorts by start time.
3. Run your list of start and end time pairs and create a TimeSpan for each, add this to a List.
4. Sort the List using the TimeSpan comparator.
5. Run the List (one time) and merge any time spans that overlap.  Overlap == if start time of 2nd TimeSpan is less than end time of 1st time stamp there is an overlap.
6. To create a merged TimeSpan, the start time is the start time of the 1st TimeStamp and the end time is which ever endtime is later (for example.  1st end time is 2p, 2nd end time is 2:01p,2nd end time is the end time of the merged TimeSpan).

   After running the list and merging spans, any time not covered by a span represents unused time.

Comment: @dah You'd reverse that, if you were open from 2-10 (8 hours) and one batch ran from 2-4 (2 hours) and another from 3-4 (1 hour) then you can take your total time open and subtract time busy: 8 - 3 = 5; in this example nothing was going for 5 hours. Parsing the timestamps and adding up times should be a pretty simple task.

Answer (score 0):

There is no arithmetical difference between those two ways of doing it. The sum of the timestamp deltas between starts and finishes of the same event is the time used, then subtracting that from the total time gives the time unused. Or, the sum of the deltas from finish time of one event to start time of the next event is the time unused, then subtracting that from the total time gives the time used. The answer is the same.

Comment: You're correct but we're talking about two machines running different batches.

Comment: I don't see how that makes any difference. If it does it would be because measuring the time from the end of one event on one machine to the start of an event on another machine is invalid, which is an argument in favour of what you're already doing.